# Разместить ссылки посредине

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте, использую библиотеку бутстрап, не выходит равномерно разместить ссылки меню по ширине блока 
[image: картинка]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav  navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="ancLinks">Услуги</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="ancLinks">О нас</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="ancLinks">Отзывы</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="ancLinks">Контакты</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1 (Задать `.navbar-nav>li { display: inline-block; }` и отменить `float`):

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav.navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav  navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="ancLinks">Услуги</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="ancLinks">О нас</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="ancLinks">Отзывы</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="ancLinks">Контакты</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Вариант 2 (добавить `flex`):

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav.navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav  navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="ancLinks">Услуги</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="ancLinks">О нас</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="ancLinks">Отзывы</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="ancLinks">Контакты</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Понятно, `разместить равномерно по ширине блока` означало отмерить равные поля по бокам :)

Answer (score 2):

Такой вариант годится?

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
  }  
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav  navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="ancLinks">Услуги</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="ancLinks">О нас</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="ancLinks">Отзывы</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="ancLinks">Контакты</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```